# Question on Lagrangian Method

Tags: optimization, self-learning, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

[image]

I have the question. And the question asks

A)Show (without solving the problem explicitly) that a solution exists to the above problem.

B) Show (without solving the problem explicitly) that there is a unique solution to the above problem.

C) show (without solving the problem explicitly) if $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $R_{++}^2$ solves the problem it must be that $x_1P_1+ x_2P_2=I$ for  $x_1>0$ and $x_2>0$

——

I can solve for this question with Lagrangian method explicitly.

Please share your knowledge with me and inform me. Thanks a lot

For part A)

Since the utility function is continuous and the constraint set is bounded and closed, there exist at least one solution by Weitress theorem.

For part B)

I check for whether the function u(.) is quasiconcave or not. For that I use hessian matrix as follows:

[image]

Since $B_1\le 0$ and $B_2>0$, this utility function is quasiconcave. But since the quasiconcavity is not strictly, there is no unique solution.

I cannot show the part C.

I am not sure about the part B and I could not do the part C.

Sorry for hand-writing, but cannot write matrix in latex. Thank you.

Comment: The authors of the question hopefully desire a **graphical** convincing reason with an "inflating" area $A_p$ where $p$ is a real parameter defined by $u(x_1,x_2) \le p$ whis a kind of (quarter) ball which reaches the limit of the region defined by $p_1x_1+p_2x_2 \le I$ which gives the "authorized" play area (= a triangle)..

Comment: Dear @JeanMarie I add what I did after your suggestion. Please can you help me to solve this question thank you.

Comment: $0.3 * 0.7 = 0.21$, not $2.1$.

Comment: Besides, have you attempted, as I advised you to consider "inflating curves", for example $u(x_1,x_2)=0.1, \ u(x_1,x_2)=0.2, \ u(x_1,x_2)=0.3, $ etc. in order to be convinced that "sooner or later" among this family of curves, one of them (and only one of them) will be tangent to the given line with equation $p_1x_1+p_2x_2=I$. If you are convinced, try to convince your instructor... But I am not sure that it is what he/she means with "without calculation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you studied the KKT conditions? You can show part C by assuming $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both positive, and that $p_1 x_1 + p_2 x_2 < I$. But this will contradict the KKT conditions, so it is not optimal. Optimality when $x_1, x_2 >0$ requires $\lambda>0$, hence the restriction is active.